# Wait for SVG to load (Ajax) before running a function

Tags: ajax, svg, load

I've really searched for days, but couldn't find a solution:

I have an external SVG (800k) which i need to load completely before calling the following function. Someone helped me with the code to load the SVG but I cant figure out how to detect when the SVG is completely loaded. (I am not using jQuery). I need the function `initialSvgSettings()` to run after the SVG has finished loading completely. Where I have it right now, it just runs when the SVG starts loading but not when it has completed.

This is the code I am using to load the SVG:

```
// LOAD SVG
var svgOverlay = viewer.svgOverlay();
var path = "images/elementosV6.svg";

function loadSVG(path, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
        try {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                callback(xhr.responseXML.documentElement);

                initialSvgSettings();
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    };

    xhr.open("GET", path, true);
    xhr.overrideMimeType("text/xml");
    xhr.responseType = "document";
    xhr.send();
}

loadSVG(path, function(data) {
    var g = data.getElementById("elements");
    svgOverlay.node().appendChild(g);
}); // FIN LOAD SVG
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer nearest to your question would be to point out that instead of using `XMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange`, you could use the [`.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) event handler, which is called only after the resource has been completely loaded.

But you can also simplify your code by loading the image into an offscreen `<object>`. Attach your callback to `.onload`, and with `.contentDocument` you can access the DOM of the SVG.

```
var svgContainer = document.createElement('object');
svgContainer.type = 'image/svg+xml';
svgContainer.onload = function () {
    var g = svgContainer.contentDocument.getElementById("elements");
    svgOverlay.node().appendChild(g);
}
svgContainer.data = 'images/elementosV6.svg';
```